# Why do CouchDB reduce functions receive 'keys' as an argument

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

With a CouchDB reduce function:

```
function(keys, values, rereduce) {
  // ...
}
```

That gets called like this:

```
reduce(  [[key1,id1], [key2,id2], [key3,id3]],    [value1,value2,value3],   false   )
```

***Question 1***

What is the reason for passing keys to the reduce function? I have only written relatively simple CouchDB views with reduce functions and would like to know what the use case is for receiving a list of `[key1, docid], [key2, docid], etc` is.

Also. is there ever a time when `key1 != key2 != keyX` when a reduce function executes?

***Question 2***

CouchDB's implementation of MapReduce allows for `rereduce=true`, in which case the reduce function is called like this:

```
reduce(null,  [intermediate1,intermediate2,intermediate3],  true)
```

Where the keys argument is  `null` (unlike when `rereduce=false`). Why would there not be a use case for a `keys` argument in this case if there was a use for when `rereduce=false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the use case of `keys` argument when `rereduce = true`?

There isn't one. That's why the `keys` argument is null in this case.

From [the documentation](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.2-docs/ddocs/ddocs.html#reduce-and-rereduce-functions) (emphasis added):

> ### Reduce and Rereduce Functions
>
> redfun(keys, values[, rereduce])
>
> #### Arguments:
>
> - `keys` – Array of pairs of key-docid for related map function results. ***Always `null` if rereduce is running (has `true` value).***
> - `values` – Array of map function result values.
> - `rereduce` – Boolean flag to indicate a rereduce run.

Perhaps what you're meaning to ask is:  Why is the same function used for both `reduce` and `rereduce`?  I expect there's some history involved, but I can also imagine that it's because it's quite common that the same logic can be used for both functions, and by not having separate function definitions duplication can be reduced.  Suppose a simple `sum` reduce function:

```
function(keys, values) {
    return sum(values);
}
```

Here both `keys` and `rereduce` can be ignored entirely.  Many other (re)reduce functions follow the same pattern.  If two functions had to be used, then this identical function would have to be specified twice.

---

In response to the additional question in comments:

> what use cases exist for the keys argument when `rereduce=false`?

Remember, `keys` and `values` can be anything, based on the map function. A common pattern is to `emit([foo,bar,baz],null)`.  That is to say, the value may be null, if all the data you care about is already present in the key.  In such a case, any reduce function more complex than a simple `sum` would require use of the keys.

Further, for grouping operations, using the keys makes sense. Consider a map function with `emit(doc.countryCode, ... )`, a possible (incomplete) reduce function:

```
function(keys, values, rereduce) {
    const sums = {};
    if (!rereduce) {
        keys.forEach((key) => ++sums[key]);
    }
    return sums;
}
```

Then given documents:

- `{"countryCode": "us", ...}`
- `{"countryCode": "us", ...}`
- `{"countryCode": "br", ...}`

You'd get emitted values (from the map function) of:

- `["us", ...]`
- `["br", ...]`

You'd a reduced result of:

`{"us": 2, "br": 1}`

Comment: I actually hadn't considered that keys were NOT passed to the rereduce function, and misspelled `reduce=true` as `rereduce=true`. But in retrospect the error makes for a pretty good question :p. Thanks for the answer; would you also be able to answer what use cases exist for the keys argument when `reduce=true`? (but `rereduce=false`)? If it's not a short answer I'll repost on SO.

Comment: There isn't a variable `reduce`; that state is just implicit when `rereduce` isn't true.  Is that what you meant?  Anyway, I updated the answer with some more details.

Comment: Thank you again! I edited the question to include more information as mentioned in the above comment. in terms of `reduce=true`, I'm referring to the CouchDB API. i.e. you can call a MapReduce index like this: `.../_design/doc/_view/someView?group=true&reduce=true`. i.e. you can call with `reduce=false`.

Comment: @ZachSmith: Ah right. That variable doesn't relate to the running of reduce functions, though; just the retrieval of the data that has already been computed.

Comment: One more question specifically for couch: the keys list is actually a list of tuples `( (key, docId), (key, docId), etc ,... )`. What is the use case for receiving the docId along with the key?

Comment: Actually... I understand that while the keys may be the same, the map is still several keys. So this would keep track of the document that prodcued the key. not sure why you need that...

Comment: If you're using a reduce function for some sort of grouping, to produce, say: `{"us":["docid1","docid2"], "br":["docid3"]}`